# How to add a "Viewed By" audit in Javers with using an explicit field on the entity being audited

Tags: javers

In our application, we have a requirement to audit "viewed by" events. Currently, we implemented this functionality by using an Audit table and manually logging it to the table during "GET" calls. I am trying to understand how to accomplish this in Javers.

In our current application, to find our changes, we use hibernate interceptor and manually add the changes to the audit table.

I thought that the easiest way to accomplish the "viewed" audit functionality in Javers is to add a "viewedBy" field to the entity being audited and manually update it in "GET" calls. But I am concerned about this approach as each time, there is a view, we are changing the version of the object(by physically updating it) and the state is being saved to the jv_snapshot table.

I expect that the viewed by audits will be part of javers.findChanges() method, so that the changes are tracked in a chronological order and also possibly be paginated.

Comment: Javers is designed for tracking changes, since `a view` is not a change it cant be tracked by Javers

Comment: thanks for the reply!